# cannot access git reposoitory

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, clone

any idea why this does not work:

```
D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\bin>"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://tobias@wdmycloud/shares/githome/Repo.git HEAD
fatal: repository 'https://tobias@wdmycloud/shares/githome/Repo.git/' not found
```

I can successfully clone this repository using eclipse:

[image: Screenshot of eclipse (that works)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, you're using SSH, and on the commandline you're using HTTPS. Those are two different protocols, and the fact that one works doesn't necessarily mean the other will work, too. Try SSH URL instead:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://tobias@wdmycloud/shares/githome/Repo.git HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [WD MyCloud, you will find tutorial to access a git repo through ssh](http://cutecoder.org/software/git-server-network-drive/), which is fairly easy to setup, considering all you need is a sshd running.

But for an https url to work, you would need an Apache server running, [properly configured](https://gist.github.com/karmi/484199#file-git-hosting-apache-conf-L55-L68) to support [`git http-backend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend).
Something along the line of `an httpd.conf` including:

```
# Configure Git HTTP Backend
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /www/example.com/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
# Note: Serve static files directly
AliasMatch ^/(.*/objects/[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38})$          /var/www/git/$1
AliasMatch ^/(.*/objects/pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx))$ /var/www/git/$1
# Note: Serve repository objects with Git HTTP backend 
ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/info/[^/]+ | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
        /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1
```

And that is not standard, unless you set it up beforehand yourself.